# Prevent layout shift with breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v5, in case that matters.

So I have a `Button` component, which should display in `fullWidth` when the user is viewing it in mobile.

I have decided to use `useMediaQuery`. Something like:

```
const smDown = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("sm"))
return (
  <Button fullWidth={smDown}>
    Label
  </Button>
);
```

Yet, since I'm using React, which uses hydration. `useMediaQuery` will first return a `false` value before returning the correct value. And this causes a layout shift when viewing on mobile.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for? Besides duplicating the component and dynamically hide one of them with `display: none`?

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your issue:

```
return (
  <Button sx={(theme)=>({[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]:{
    width: '100%',
    }
    })}>
    Label
  </Button>
);
```